# options for solving one way audio issue during voip call?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Buying a new phone may be one solution, but that would be a shame. :-)

Huawei G500 Pro (U8836D)  ICS 4.0.4

From the outset, voip/sip calls using *any* application would have the problem of what would seem to be one way audio; the person at the other end (whether initiating or receiving a call) can not hear anything being spoken (from the G500) but at the G500 the other party is clear as a bell.

I have read many articles across the internet, but there does not seem to be a definitive answer/solution and certainly not one that has worked for me so far.

I have tried many apps making changes to the various settings where facilitated. I have also tried the MTK engineer settings to adjust volumes etc in the hope it may cajole it to work.

In addition, a different ROM has been flashed (the one from BGCNGM [Bruno] on the xda developer site) for amongst other things to see if that fixed anything. It did not; same situation as with the stock.

If any one knows what the issue actually is (module missing or faulty, kernel issue etc) and has a solution(s) to try, that would be great.  I can live without it, but it would be nice to see if it could be resolved ?

Thank you for any ideas and apologies if it seems a bit of an open-ended question.